How to get the value of column with corresponding max value of another column
I have a table with columns A,B,C.For for each value of colC I want to chose the colB value with the max value of colA
I cant use a Group By as it leads out col b
I have:

I want:

This Has probably been asked before, but I cant an answer to this in here.

I am not following the logic, can you clarify what you mean by for each value of ColC, choose value in ColB with the max value of ColC ? why would ColC val = 1 be the max value?

I suppose you messed up your explanation. Are you looking for the rows with the maximum ColA for each ColC? If so, can it happen that there are two rows with the same ColC and ColA? If so, which row(s) to show then?

And please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy and paste the data as formatted text into the request instead.

You can use a windows function. Your description of what you want is confusing, but it simply looks like you want the row with max of colA grouped by colC. This assumes your DBMS (which you didn't tag) supports the row_number() windows function.
select colA, colB, colC
from (
  select colA, colB, colC, 
   row_number() over (partition by colC order by colA desc) as rn
  from table1
)z
where rn = 1
order by colC;

See this fiddle

Very good solution! I didn't know the partition method, and I can see how powerfull it is. Thank you very much. Answer accepted!

How about this ? (like in the table you displayed).
SELECT colA,
    colB,
    colC
FROM My_Table
GROUP BY colC
HAVING colA = MAX(colA);


This is invalid SQL. You GROUP BY colC, so you get one result row per colC value. In the HAVING clause, you want colA = MAX(colA), but which colA? There can be many colA values per colC value and in the HAVING clause you are no longer looking at single rows, but at aggregation results. colA is not an aggregation result and cannot be used there hence. Same for colA and colB in your SELECT clause. As you GROUP BY colC, you must tell the DBMS which colA value and which colB value to show; there ain't just one colA and one colB per colC.

Yep, sorry, my intention is never to downvote people; I upvote and downvote answers in order to show which answers to consider. This is how stackoverflow works, and this is why the best answers are usually the first to show up when someone looks for an answer to their problem.

@R_User_001 If you care about reputation, you are wrong here. This site's purpose is to help people to solve issues, not to win a reputation race. Anyway, you can use a fiddle site to try out your code before writing an answer. That would both increase your chances to get upvotes and also make it more likely your answer solves a problem.

@Jonas Metzler maybe I was not clear. As I said in my comment, "the idea was still to try to help". What I meant, is that if you post an answer, basically, you're doing it to help people solve the issue; and therefore, even if you do not solve it, there should not be any negative result (whether it's a reputation loss, or anything else). I don't know if it makes more sense now ?
P.S : thanks for the fiddle site advice; actually, I did try with some of my training data in MySQL Workbench, but as data are not the same, it's hard to be sure it will work.
